# How to recover lost username?

Tags: username

I have a blog (www.ahsrocketlaunch.org) and need to update to the latest version of wordpress.  However, I cannot remember the username I used to set up the wordpress account.  therefore, I can't access the account to update WordPress.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. Self-hosted WordPress is not related to the wordpress.com hosted blogging service. Questions about wordpress.com support issues (such as recovering a lost password) [are explicitly out of scope for WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). **NOTE:** based on the URL you provided, you're not using wordpress.com, but rather have a self-hosted WordPress install.

Comment: This site is hosted on GoDaddy according to the traceroute.

Comment: To clear up comment confusion - questions seems to initially had "wordpress.com" in title, although it seems to be about self-hosted installation.

Comment: @Rarst: yep, I realized that the title didn't match the question only *after* casting a close vote. So, I changed the title to clarify, but left my original close-vote reason comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few easy steps to take:

1. Go to your host management panel ([GoDaddy docs here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5942/using-phpmyadmin-to-manage-mysql-databases)) and open phpMyAdmin.
2. Navigate to your WordPress installation database
3. Navigate to the *wp*_users table and you will see all of your users and email information
4. Go to your WP installation login screen and reset your password there with the username you see in the database

You can also change your password within phpMyAdmin. Check out my post [here](http://upthemes.com/blog/2011/06/reset-wordpress-password-via-phpmyadmin/) to see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress redirects `author=id` query to `author/username` and in most cases user with id 1 is the admin.
So, you can get the username of admin by following this url:

```
example.com/?author=1
```

and viewing the redirected url.